# Get a field value in the proper way

Tags: 8, entities

In a custom module, I use the following code to get a field value.

```php
$value = $user->get('field_value')->getValue();
```

The returned value is an array. To get a scalar value contained in that array, I should use one of the following lines.

```php
$value = reset(reset($user->get('field_value')->getValue()));
```

```php
$value = $user->get('field_value')->getValue()[0]['value'];
```

Is there a Drupal, simpler way to get the scalar value contained in the array?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The method `getValue()` is used to get an array:

```
$array = $user->get('field_value')->getValue();
```

If you want to get a scalar use:

```
$value = $user->get('field_value')->value;
```

Both methods look similar, but do different things:

- The method `getValue()` is to get the complete array of a field, which is quite useful for multiple value fields or multiple properties.
- The method `->value` gets the property with the same name. Most standard fields use `value` as the main property.

Comment: 4x4 answer is very valuable. However, it is a mistake to assume that `->value` is appropriate. If you don't know, and you probably don't, check the object returned from `$value = $user->get('field_value');` One clue is the kind of field that your targeting. If it is text field `value` is probably correct. If it an entity reference field, it will most likely be `target_id`

Comment: @sea26.2, most times you probably want to use the property `entity`, though. See the discussion about specific field types here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/252333/how-to-get-formatted-date-string-from-a-datetimeitem-object/252341#comment308848_252341