# Updating author name in preprocessnode

Tags: theming, nodes, 8

The `kpr` line in the function works – It outputs the author of the node's full name. But setting the `author_name` variable **does not**. Why isn't that replacing the `author_name` variable in my template? (It's just blank.)

If i remove this, it will display the username.

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // die(kpr($variables['node']->getOwner()->get('field_full_name')->getValue()));
  $variables['author_name'] = $variables['node']->getOwner()->get('field_full_name')->getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

getValue() is probably returning an array, which cannot be interpreted by twig. try:

```
$variables['author_name'] = $variables['node']->getOwner()->get('field_full_name')->getValue()['value'];
```

Or search for the right key in there ..

Comment: Yes, `->getValue()` gets an array. Instead you can use `->value`, see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/drupal-8-get-value-of-field-user-in-proper-way-not-an-array

Comment: cool hint , thx ;)