# Getting the "processed" value of a formatted text field

Tags: 9, input-formats

I have a formatted text field on a content type that I'm using as the body of an email. If I load the node and print out the field I get:

```
>>> $n->field_thankyou_email_body->getValue()
=> [
     [
       "value" => "<b>Thanks!!</b>",
       "format" => "subscriber_text_lb",
     ],
   ]
```

The array is missing the "processed" value, how do I get that? Or alternatively how do I manually run the value through the text format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A field property is accessed like an object property:

```
$node->field_formatted_text->processed
```

As a side note, use this only for cases like this which are outside of the page render context. The preferable way is to render the text field in a render array to preserve attached metadata. See [How to safely render node body on a custom variable?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/238762/how-to-safely-render-node-body-on-a-custom-variable)

Comment: oh so even though the debug doesn't show it, the property is accessible, thanks.

Comment: Yes, this is because it is a computed property. Like `entity` of a reference field or `date` of a datetime field. See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/252341/47547

Comment: I'm getting object unless I typecast as below,
`(string) $entity->get('field_formatted_text')->processed;`