# how easy it is to get the date when the order is completed?

Tags: entities, commerce

I need to get the due date (payment) of the last order, but I got some kind of crooked code.

I receive all user orders by request.

```
      $allOrders = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('commerce_order')->loadByProperties(
    ['state' => 'completed',
      'uid' => $uid,
    ]);
```

I cannot figure out why the following code is not working

```
$allOrders[111]->values["completed"]["x-default"]
```

The following code worked for me, I think it is wrong and unnecessary.

```
      $IndexAr = array_key_last($allOrders);
  $oneIndex = $allOrders[$IndexAr];
  $AllValues = $oneIndex->toArray();
  $DataTime = $AllValues["completed"][0]["value"];
```

Here is the data structure:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drupal 8, get value of field user in proper way, not an array](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/drupal-8-get-value-of-field-user-in-proper-way-not-an-array)

Comment: @Hudri Thanks a lot, worked:       $IndexAr = array_key_last($allOrders);
      $DataTime = $allOrders[$IndexAr]->get('completed')->value;